# Generated class by protoc generates compile errors

Tags: protocol-buffers

I created a simple .proto file and executed the compiler (protoc-2.5.0rc1-win32.zip). A java file was generated to the prescribed package. However, the generated file does not compile. 
The .proto file is simple with a single message with a bunch of simple types optional fields (properly numbered).
The .java file does not compile, for example:

- The constructor GeneratedMessage.FieldAccessorTable(Descriptors.Descriptor, String[]) is undefined
- The method ensureFieldAccessorsInitialized(Class, Class) is undefined for the type GeneratedMessage.FieldAccessorTable
- ... and host of other errors along the same line (like trying to override a final method in superclass)

errors that hint at some mismatch at the level of the API version?
Any ideas?

Thanks
RESOLVED: found that the version of proto expected by the API I am using is 2.4.1 and I was using latest.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I tracked this down to [akka](/questions/tagged/akka) including an older prototype buffer version, and the versions conflicted.

**Solution:** Check all your libraries for older versions of prototype buffer, it may be included in something you have already.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved the same problem.
the answer:
1.show your protoc complier version

e.g.
D:\workspace2\monitor\src\main\resources>protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1

2.make the protoc jar coincident with your protoc complier version

e.g.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you first need to build a new protocol buf jar ( protobuf-java-2.5.0rc1.jar ) from the source distribution protobuf-2.5.0rc1.zip and make this a local "system" dependency of your maven pom.xml. I also get compile errors if i just produce new java stubs with the new compiler but have the old 2.4.1 jar dependency in my pom. I couldnt find a maven repository which hosts the 2.5.0rc1.jar already built. If you just take the source files from the source distribution , you miss some class files like com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.*.